# What subspace is I-AA$^\dagger$ on?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

A is an m x n matrix with rank n. I'm trying to prove that I - AA$^\dagger$ is an orthogonal projection operator, and I believe I did that already. I just can't figure out what subspace this is on. I already know AA$^\dagger$ is in $\Bbb R ^m$.

To clarify, A$^\dagger$ is the pseudo inverse.

Comment: The only reasonable description is "the image (column space) of $A$".  Do we know more about $A$?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen It doesn't specify.

Comment: To specify, A$^\dagger$ is the pseudo inverse

Comment: @user409800 Ahh, usually $\dagger$ represents adjoint and $+$ is pseudoinverse (you might add that to the problem). Makes more sense now. Deleting irrelevant comment.

Comment: @user409800 And yes, then $I-AA^+$ projects onto the orthogonal complement of the column space of $A$